# FIle format in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have multiple format files in a blob storage ,how to check format of  only csv files and move that into another folder in azure data factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the GetMetadata activity to list the files. Be sure to add the "ChildItems" property:
[image]

Next use a Filter activity to only process the items that match your criteria:
[image]

NOTE: this example only processes a) files [ignores subfolders] that b) name starts with "scoring-" and c) ends in ".csv".

Now you can perform the move inside the a ForEach over the filtered list:
[image]

Comment: One more query I have  multiple excel files in a blob storage and sheet name in those files are different while loading in the files in azure sql database  in azure data flow how the sheet name to be handled.really appreciate for the help

Comment: That's a different issue, you'll need to create a new question.